# How to read and delete first n lines from file in Python - Elegant Solution[2]

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Originally posted here: [How to read and delete first n lines from file in Python - Elegant Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630639/how-to-read-and-delete-first-n-lines-from-file-in-python-elegant-solution)

I have a pretty big file ~ 1MB in size and I would like to be able to read first N lines, save them into a list (**newlist**) for later use, and then delete them.

My original code was:

```
import os

n = 3 #the number of line to be read and deleted

with open("bigFile.txt") as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()

newlist = mylist[:n]
os.remove("bigFile.txt")

thefile = open('bigFile.txt', 'w')

del mylist[:n]

for item in mylist:
  thefile.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Based on [Jean-François Fabre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%C3%A7ois-fabre) code that was posted and later **deleted** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064184/remove-lines-from-textfile-with-python) I am able to run the following code:

```
import shutil

n = 3

with open("bigFile.txt") as f, open("bigFile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    for _ in range(n):
        next(f)
    f2.writelines(f)
```

This works great for deleting the first n lines and "updating" the bigFile.txt but when I try to store the first n values into a list so I can later use them like this:

```
with open("bigFile.txt") as f, open("bigFile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()
    newlist = mylist[:n]
    for _ in range(n):
        next(f)
    f2.writelines(f)
```

I get an "StopIteration" error

Comment: As a hint ... `f.read().splitlines()` consumes the entire file ...

Comment: Your file is already exhausted. you need to go back to the beggining of the file with `fo.seek(0, 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code you are reading the entire file to find the first `n` lines:

```
# this consumes the entire file
mylist = f.read().splitlines()
```

This leaves nothing left to read for the subsequent code.  Instead simply do:

```
with open("bigFile.txt") as f, open("bigFile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    # read the first n lines into newlist
    newlist = [f.readline() for _ in range(n)]
    f2.writelines(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed as follows:

```
n = 3
yourlist = []
with open("bigFile.txt") as f, open("bigFile2.txt", "w") as f2:
    i=0
    for line in f:
        i += 1
        if i<n:
            yourlist.append(line)
        else:
            f2.write(f)
```